# net.IP as map key type in golang?

Tags: go

I have map with key as net.IP and value as a channel.
But I'm getting a weird compile time error (invalid map key type)

```
17 type UdpServer struct {
18     ListenPort int
19
20     ConnRef *net.UDPConn
21     Log_ref *Logger
22     MapOfValues map[net.IP]chan string
23 }


$ go build c-manager.go
cmanager/c-udp_server.go:22:14: invalid map key type net.IP

$ go version
  go version go1.10.2 linux/amd64
```

What am I doing wrong? Can't we have net.IP as map key type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [net.IP](https://godoc.org/net#IP) is a slice type.  Because slices are mutable, they cannot be used as map keys. Use a string as the key type:

```
MapOfValues map[string]chan string
```

Use a [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to convert from net.IP to string and back. Use [IP.To16](https://godoc.org/net#IP.To4) to normalize addresses to the 16 byte representation.

```
x.MapOfValues[string(ip.To16())] = v

for k, v := range x.MapOfValues {
   ip := net.IP(k) // convert string to net.IP
   ...
}
```

If you want the keys to be printable, then use the [IP.String](https://godoc.org/net#IP.String) and [net.ParseIP](https://godoc.org/net#ParseIP) functions to do the conversions:

```
x.MapOfValues[ip.String()] = v

for k, v := range x.MapOfValues {
   ip := net.ParseIP(k) 
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Starting with Go 1.18 you can now use [`netip.Addr`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/netip#Addr) directly as map key. One of the declared intents of this new IP type is exactly to support `==` and `!=` operators, therefore allowing usage as map keys.

> Addr represents an IPv4 or IPv6 address (with or without a scoped addressing zone), similar to net.IP or net.IPAddr.
>
> Unlike net.IP or net.IPAddr, **Addr is a comparable value type (it supports == and can be a map key)** and is immutable.

So now you can declare your struct field as:

```
MapOfValues map[netip.Addr]chan string
```